# Would trolls be monkeys or apes

Tags: evolution, mythical-creatures

In a world I'm working on, one of the many creatures is the troll. The details of trolls shouldn't be too important for this question, other than evolution and the fact that they have a tail. Trolls are descended from the sasquatch, which falls into the *Homo* genus, however, trolls themselves are part of the *Troglodytam* genus. My question is since trolls have tails but are descended from apes, are they monkeys, apes, or something else.

Comment: You're asking us what the correct nomenclature would be for a fictitious species of ape that had over the course of evolution reacquired a tail, oddly enough that sounds like  a real world question to me, one for the appropriate discipline, the clue is in their evolutionary history that you gave us, you already said it yourself, they're hominids and apes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they're part of the homo genus then by definition they are hominids. Hominids by definition are great apes.

The tail is possible since even humans have tail bones (coccyx).

Comment: I agree with this answer but i must note that trolls are part of a different genus, however still hominids.

Comment: The "hominid" term is not a corollary to the homo genus. In fact, any species in the homo genus is "human". Hominids are all apes except gibbons. [See this for all the different, but very similar terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominidae#:~:text=A%20hominid%20is%20a%20member,tribe%20Hominini%3A%20chimpanzees%20and%20humans.).

Comment: @frеdsbend pretty much what I said isn't it? Great apes = all apes except gibbons

Comment: Yes, sorry. Reading into your first sentence too much. I read it as equivalency, that all in homo genus are hominids (true) *and* that all hominids are in homo genus (not true).

Answer (score 1):

The tail rule is really a quick-hand, not a hard rule. Take the Mandrill for an example. They have this little nub, which most call a tail, but you could make the case that it's not a tail, since it doesn't seem to have any use except as an occasional handle that weary mothers hold tight.

Also, whether it's a "monkey" or "ape" (or something else) is a matter of Taxonomy, which is not a science, but a convenient tool of science. Most taxonomic conventions today take evolutionary provenance into great consideration. With that in mind, it makes a good case the Troll is an Ape. That the Troll is given an entirely different genus doesn't seem to be a conflict at all. From my understanding, all the Great Apes are in the family [Hominidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominidae) and are differentiated from there by genus and species.

To illustrate the subjective and changing nature of Taxonomy, consider that at one time only Humans were considered the only living Hominids:

> Hominidae has been a subject of much debate among taxonomists. Formerly, humans alone (with their extinct forebears) were placed in Hominidae, and the great apes were placed in a different family, Pongidae.
> [Hominidae - Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/animal/Hominidae)

See [the History of hominoid taxonomy on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape#History_of_hominoid_taxonomy) for more information.

And also, consider where on this chart your troll ends up:

> [image: Human Evolutionary Chart - Britannica]
> *[ibid](https://www.britannica.com/animal/Hominidae)*

It looks to me like the Troll is a fork at or after Hominin.

**But none of these related creatures have tails!**

Pragmatically, so what? Will your readership care or even notice? I say, [if Rocket from Guardians having a tail doesn't bother anybody](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/145927/458), then no one really cares that much why a biped will have a tail. You can hand-wave this one.

However, if you want to be really precise, I see two options.

1. Put it in a different Family, one that already has tails, then explain how it became human-like.
2. Leave it in the Hominidade Family and explain how it got a tail.

Option 1 is more interesting to me, and leaves open the "vestigial structure" argument. Option 2 means the tail has to do something useful for the Troll's survival ... I'm losing interest already.